# How to encrypt passwords on client with REST ASP.NET Web API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin, openapi

I have a standard latest version (not Core) ASP.NET Web API platform where I have to encrypt user passwords on the client in case SSL/HTTPS is not used.

What would be the standard way to do this?

This is BB application with a few consumers serving several users (so there could also be security on the client level).

(As the accounts are used in other application, it has to be encryption, no hashing)

Comment: the standard way would be use https

Answer (score -1):

There is a "standard" protocol for this SRP - Secure Remote Password protocol.  There is a NuGet package.
(What I need is a bit simpler, but I still think its the solution)[Wikipedia on SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol)

[GitHub location Nuget project](https://github.com/secure-remote-password/srp.net)